# Why does Veracode report CWE-89?

Tags: java, sql, sql-injection, spring-jdbc, veracode

I have this SQL query written in JDBC which contains dynamic table and fields names:

```
    private String checkDimension(String tenantId, String prefix, Long schemaMetaId, Long transactionalMetaId,
                                  String dimension, String dimensionValue) {
        DataSource tenantDataSource = tenantDataSourceProvider.getTenantDataSource(checkEntityName(tenantId));
        try (Connection connection = tenantDataSource.getConnection()) {

            String sql = String.format("select * from \"%s_%s\" input_file join \"DIMENSION_VALUES_%s\" dv on " +
                            "(dv.\"DIMENSION\" = ? and dv.\"DIMENSION_VALUE\" = input_file.\"%s\") limit 1",
                    checkEntityName(prefix), checkEntityName(schemaMetaId.toString()),
                    checkEntityName(transactionalMetaId.toString()), checkEntityName(dimensionValue));
            try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                statement.setString(1, dimension);
                try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                    if (resultSet.next()) {
                        return "OK";
                    } else {
                        return "Values do not match";
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(exception);
        }
    }
```

For mitigation flaws I am using function `checkEntityName` which should silent them (make them false positive during Veracode scan)

```
    @SQLQueryCleanser
    static String checkEntityName(String entityName) {
        if (!entityName.matches("^[-a-zA-Z0-9_]*$")) {
            throw new SecurityException(String.format("Invalid name for entity: %s", entityName));
        }
        return entityName;
    }
```

But Veracode is still reporting this issue:

Flaw Id: 1433

Description: This database query contains a SQL injection flaw. The call to java.sql.Statement.executeQuery() constructs a dynamic SQL query using a variable derived from untrusted input. An attacker could exploit this flaw to execute arbitrary SQL queries against the database. The first argument to executeQuery() contains tainted data from the variable format(). The tainted data originated from an earlier call to java.sql.Statement.executeQuery.

Remediation: Avoid dynamically constructing SQL queries. Instead, use parameterized prepared statements to prevent the database from interpreting the contents of bind variables as part of the query. Always validate untrusted input to ensure that it conforms to the expected format, using centralized data validation routines when possible.

Can you please give me advice how to solve this? Thank you :)

Comment: I assume that `checkEntityName()` throws an exception if the parameter is not all valid identifier characters? If so, then your code is safe, but Veracode doesn't know what `checkEntityName()` does, so it doesn't know you already guarded against SQL injection. --- Do a web search for [`Veracode ignore`](https://www.google.com/search?q=Veracode+ignore) to find options for suppressing the issue for that particular code.

Comment: I would love to know if you made any progress on this.

Answer (score 0):

If it still gives an exception even using `PrepareStatement` try to sanitize the native SQL query string by using the below code.

```java
private static String sanitizeQuery(String query) {
    return query
        .chars()
        .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```